# Get list of all database users with specified role

Tags: t-sql

I want to get list of all database users with specified role. Role is a parameter for stored procedure or function.

Somethinf like a select statement with user name and its role.

```
+============+==========
| User name  |  Role   |
+============+==========
```

MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: are you talking about the system roles or application roles?

Comment: i'm talking about database roles and database users.

Answer (score 47):

In SQL 2005 and 2008 this information is most easily accessed in two catalog views.

This query should give you the information you're looking for.

```
select rp.name as database_role, mp.name as database_user
from sys.database_role_members drm
join sys.database_principals rp on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
join sys.database_principals mp on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)
```

Comment: Enhanced to list the Login and Authentication type  
SELECT rp.name AS DatabaseRole
   ,mp.name AS Member
   ,mp.[type_desc] AS LoginType
   ,mp.authentication_type_desc AS AuthType
FROM  sys.database_role_members drm
JOIN  sys.database_principals rp ON drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id
JOIN  sys.database_principals mp ON drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id

Answer (score 5):

just depending on how you want to pass the parameter...assuming you'll use the id of the role

```
declare @roleID int

select
    role_principal_id as roleID, 
    user_name(role_principal_id) as roleName, 
    member_principal_id as memberID,
    user_name(member_principal_id) as memberName 
from 
    sys.database_role_members
where 
    role_principal_id = @roleID
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably use something like this

```
SELECT
    SU.Name AS UserName, SR.Name AS RoleName
FROM
    sysUsers AS SU
      INNER JOIN 
     sysUsers AS SR ON SU.GID = SR.UID
WHERE
    SU.GID <> SU.UID
ORDER BY
  RoleName, UserName
```

Borrowed from [SmartBihari's Blog](http://smartbihari.blogspot.com/2007/05/list-of-database-users-by-role.html)

**EDIT 1**  To Get the System Roles associated with a user.
  The sys.sysmembers is a system view which has the memberuid and the groupuid as the only columns. you can use the user_name() function to retreive the name of each column.

```
USE [YourDatabase]
SELECT user_name([memberuid]) as [Username], User_Name([groupuid]) as [Role_Name]
FROM [sys].[sysmembers]
```

Comment: it's not returned role names of users.

Comment: sys.sysmembers is from SQL-Server 2000.  2005/2008 are backward compatible, so no problem (yet), but if you're just learning how to do this in 2008, then I'd recommend using sys.database_role_members instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can help you:

```
        select sys.server_role_members.role_principal_id ,role.name  as rolename    
        , sys.server_role_members.member_principal_id , member.name as membername 
        from sys.server_role_members 
        join sys.server_principals as role
        on sys.server_role_members.role_principal_id = role.principal_id
        join sys.server_principals as member 
        on sys.server_role_members. member_principal_id = member_principal_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note for others that may be interested.

MS SQL Tips has a procedure that provides a great list, and db info. It makes this a procedure in the master db so it may be called across dbs on the server.

They too have many other cool scripts.
Here is the link.
Enjoy!

[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/[enter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/%5Benter) link description here][1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5999/sql-server-database-users-to-roles-mapping-report/)