# Listing ALL users on a specific database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to list all users on a specific database.

When I use the sys.server_principals or sys.sysmembers system views it does not list all the users that appear under the Security -> Users list in the Object Browser in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is what I attempted:

```sql
USE [Database_Name];

SELECT user_name([memberuid]) as [Username]
FROM [sys].[sysmembers];

USE [Database_Name];

SELECT [name]
FROM [sys].[server_principals];
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of all database users with specified role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361778/get-list-of-all-database-users-with-specified-role)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `sysmembers` or `sysusers` for this - all the `sys___` views are are backward compatibility views and (a) will be dropped from the product at some point and (b) won't necessarily contain current information.

If you are looking for database principals, don't look in `sys.server_principals`, look in [`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx).

```
USE your_database;
GO

SELECT name, create_date, type_desc
  FROM sys.database_principals
  WHERE is_fixed_role = 0;
```

This will include things like `guest`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, `dbo`, `public` and `sys`. However it won't include accounts like `sa` which have inherent rights over the database without needing an explicit principal defined.

Comment: Thanks!  I feel like a bit of a noob now :-)

Comment: +1 I originally suggested `sysusers`, I've just checked and the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179871.aspx) say it is only there for backwards compatibility. Aaron is of course correct - these system views are the (newer) replacements.